# Auxiliary Shaft Sprocket

Tags: ford, timing-belt

I have an '89 ford ranger that loses power and stutters intermittently around 2000 rpm.

I thought this could be a timing issue.  The Camshaft Sprocket and Crank pulley are lined up nicely but the oil pump sprocket is way off.

What symptoms will this cause and could this be related to the issues I'm seeing?

[image]

Comment: The position of the oil pump sprocket won't affect anything.

Comment: Which fuel does this engine use?

Comment: gasoline, 4 cylinder 2.6 L engine.  2 wheel drive

Comment: @HandyHowie unfortunately that still leaves me with the stuttering problem and no leads

Comment: Can you better describe your "stutter"? And @HandyHowie is spot on ... the intermediate sprocket will have zero effect on timing or your stutter. Is the engine carb'd or fuel injected? (I'd assume carb'd, but I want to make sure.)

Comment: Do you experience any sputtering or issues below and above 2000 rpm?   If so, what kind symptoms do you experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Possible Issues/Symptoms

**You Asked**

> What symptoms will this cause and could this be related to the issues I'm seeing?

- A clogged catalytic converter.  A clogged catalytic converter can cause many of these symptoms.  See this Q&A regarding [bad catalytic converters from @Zaid.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-bad-cats)
- Clogged fuel injectors.  If they are having any type of restriction you may have a lean condition
- Bad fuel pump.  This can result in fuel starvation and reflects the symptoms you are seeing.
- Bad/Damaged 02 sensor.  If your O2 sensors are bad this can result in sending bad data to the ECU.  The ECU may be telling the injectors to send the wrong amount of fuel due to the bad data the ECU is receiving.

There are more possible issues that another resource may be able to illuminate for you.

The oil pump pulley doesn't need to be 'timed' so that should not be a concern.

**Timing**

If you are seeing your cam and crank timed properly together then this is more than likely not your issue.